# Fennel mandarin salad

Tags: cutting

I have a recipe for a fennel mandarin salad. it says to chop the fennel bulb. I haven't cooked or even ate fennel before. I have the fennel. Do i chop the green portion or the white bulb portion? for this salad?

Comment: It is almost certainly the white bulb or root, which should be peeled as well.  If you can provide the full recipe, you might get a better answer.

Answer (score 1):

As it says, you chop the bulb - the white part at the bottom. The core of the bulb can sometimes be a bit tough, especially at the bottom, and you may have to remove the drier outer layer, but otherwise, that's the part you really want to use.

The bulb is juicy and easy to eat, while the green stalks are usually much more fibrous - think celery, except tougher. If you do want to eat the stalks fresh, you can try slicing them relatively thinly, so you don't have long strands of fiber to try to chew. Alternatively, they're great for adding flavor to soups and stews; you can just fish them out after they've released their flavor.